# Custom Feedback form with slidedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown

I've created custom Feedback form but the problem is when i click on First tab it's slides the form witch is like i want but when is slided down and i click on the last tab i dont want to start sliding again. I want to be the same as: http://www.feedbackify.com/ (click on feedback to see demo).
js:

```
  $(function () {
        $('#other').click(function () {
            $(".details").hide();
            $('#other-slide').slideDown('slow');
        });

        $('#problem').click(function () {
            $(".details").hide();
            $('#problem-slide').slideDown('slow');
        });

    });
```

My demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VnXaU/1/

Please help me finish this form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did `some mods in the script` and one `wrapper div for the sliders`.

```
<div class='form-wrapper'>
  ......slider divs.....
</div>
```

### and jQuery:

```
$('#problem, #other').click(function () {
      var ID = this.id;
      if ($('.form-wrapper').is(':not(:visible)')) {
          $('.form-wrapper').slideDown('fast').promise().done(function () {
              $('[id="' + ID + '-slide"]').fadeIn('slow');
          });
      } else {
          $('[id$="-slide"]').hide();
          $('[id="' + ID + '-slide"]').fadeIn('slow');
      }
  });
```

[**find in this fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnXaU/5/)